# Can't create procedure on DB2

Tags: sql, db2, procedure

I want to create a procedure that deletes some records. Here is what I did so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYSCHEMA.PROC_DELETE_MISSING()
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN 

For v_row as select ID myid from MyTABLE t1 where t1.IS_MISSING='D'
    DO
        delete MYTABLE2 t2 where t2.ID = v_row.myid;

END FOR


END
```

I get some errors saying that a semicolon is missing ! What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer the question about the semicolon, but why are you doing a loop?  You can express this as a single statement:

```
delete MYTABLE2 t2
    where t2.ID in (select id from mytable t1 where t1.is_missing = 'D');
```

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon is missing after the `END FOR` because you need to terminate that statement within the procedure.